# Why intercept pod/bindings but fail to fetch its corresponding pod in kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have a project that `intercepts pod/bindings resources by mutatingwebhook`, then `gets the corresponding pod and adds a label`.

Part of the code is as follows

```
# k8s webhookconfig
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: mutation
webhooks:
- name: mutationpod
  rules:
  - operations: ["CREATE"]
    apiGroups: [""]
    apiVersions: ["v1"]
    resources: ["pods/binding"]
  failurePolicy: Fail
  sideEffects: None
```

```
# webhook server
func (p *PodMutate) Handle(ctx context.Context, req admission.Request) admission.Response {
    podBinding := &corev1.Binding{}
    podMutateLog := log.WithName("PodMutate")

    err := p.decoder.Decode(req, podBinding)
    if err != nil {
        podMutateLog.Error(err, "failed decoder podBinding")
        return admission.Errored(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    }

    pod := &corev1.Pod{}
    if err = p.Client.Get(ctx, types.NamespacedName{Namespace: podBinding.Namespace, Name: podBinding.Name}, pod); err != nil {
        if apierrors.IsNotFound(err) {
            podMutateLog.Error(err, fmt.Sprintf("pod %s in namespace %s not found", podBinding.Name, podBinding.Namespace))
        } else if statusError, isStatus := err.(*apierrors.StatusError); isStatus {
            podMutateLog.Error(err, fmt.Sprintf("error getting pod %s in namespace %s: %v", podBinding.Name, podBinding.Namespace, statusError.ErrStatus.Message))
        } else {
            podMutateLog.Error(err, fmt.Sprintf("failed to get pod %s: %v", podBinding.Name, err))
        }
        return admission.Allowed("")
    }
...
...
```

But it **unexpectedly** got an error that `the pod could not be found`, of course, this is an accidental error that I found after deploying the service many times.

```
{"lever":"error",...,"msg":"pod nginx-deployment-xxx in namespace default not found"}...
```

So I added a `retry mechanism` to read the pod and so far this error doesn't happen again. **But I want to know why this is?**

I really appreciate any help with this.

> PS: Code reference [controller-runtime example](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/tree/master/examples/builtins)